# USB supply protection using Schottky diode

Tags: usb, circuit-protection, diode-clamp

Here is the attached schematic of the clamping diode condition. I isolated the connection to controller and kept the end open. When USB input is varied above 5V the expected output is diode cathode voltage (5V) + diode drop, which I was getting when I'm simulating the same.

I tried to test the same condition on board level by varying the USB input above 5V, I'm seeing the same USB input voltage at output (diode anode). Please let me know what is the problem in real case.

[image]

Comment: what's the problem? This sounds right.

Comment: Testing result it not same as simulation. If  USB input is 10 V(continuous input), the  voltage is at diode anode is 10V, but the actual to be 5v + diode drop. Let us know how to test this.

Comment: The diode is named after the German physicist Walter H. Schottky. It is also called Schottky (with a capital 'S').

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because your +5V supply can't sink current.  In simulation, that 5V source will stay at 5V no matter what, but on the bench that 60 ohm resistor can probably provide plenty of current for your 5V circuitry and then some.  Unless your power supply has the capability to sink current in order to maintain the output voltage at 5V, that 5V node will drift up to the input voltage until something dies and shorts.  You can verify if this is the case by measuring your +5V supply to see if it tracks USB VCC.

Comment: How can I test this clamping condition on bench.

Comment: As mentioned above, check your +5V supply line and see if it's tracking the USB VCC.